# I can't launch recently installed games on Windows Vista?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, windows-vista

I recently installed *Anno 1503*, *Mafia*, and *Praetorians* on my PC. After installing each one, not one of them will work leading me to believe these are not individual issues relating to each but one.

I have Steam installed but haven't used it for any of the aforementioned games.

Upon installing each one, I went into the properties of each and set them to run as admin but to no avail. When I try to launch, I'm asked to allow the program to run but nothing else happens... no error msg, nothing.

I have also

- Restarted my PC
- Tested other games. Fallout 3 and Morrowind still run. Rome Total War, which used to run fine, no longer works either
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled Notepad++ as a test, and that launches fine still

Any ideas? Feel free to ask for any further info.

My PC specs:

- Vista Home Premium (SP2) 64-bit
- Intel Core2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz
- 8GB Ram
- NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT
- DirectX 11

Comment: have you restarted since?

Comment: Yes, several times.

Comment: Also, Rome Total War (which I have had installed for a few years) no longer runs. I haven't played it recently but recall it working fine in the past.

Comment: Do games you installed before these still run? Are you using something like Steam or GoG to run/install these games? Does any new program not run, for instance if you install notepad++ or something simple will that run?

Comment: Not a single one of the games you listed actually advertise Windows Vista compatibility on systemrequirementslab.com. as such, I am voting to close this question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking why their games are not working on an operating system that is not listed under the supported system for said titles. If you wish to know why these restrictions occur, perhaps super user would be a better option.

Comment: Will still note that you might be able to upgrade to 7 and run in XP compatibility mode.

Comment: @Timelord64 only one game is even added to that site? Also they do work on vista, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praetorians_(video_game)#Gameplay, http://forums.2k.com/showthread.php?24145-Mafia-On-Vista, (couldn't find anything for anno 1503)

Comment: @Aequitas, I checked each one myself. I take systemrequirementslab over a wiki, though.

Comment: Fallout 3 and Morrowind still run. I have Steam installed but haven't used it for any of the aforementioned games. Uninstalled and reinstalled notepad++ and that launches fine still.

Comment: @user130843 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @user130843, it doesnt really work that way. Fallout 3 and Morrowind may work, where others would not. Atleast Fallout 3 is significantly newer, there, too.

Comment: @Aequitas 64-bit

Comment: @Timelord64 As I said, I have had Rome Total War running on this system before and now that has stopped so compatibility shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @Timelord64 can you link me to the sys req lab site for praetorians and anno 1503, I couldn't find it. Also just because it's not listed doesn't mean it won't work

Comment: My bad. It was gamesystemrequirements.com ( [Anno](http://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/anno-1503) , [Praetorians](http://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/praetorians) ). I'm not saying it won't work, I'm saying that questions about why a game will not work for a OS it is not listed for is off-topic.

Comment: Also, Total War lists Vista as compatible. Maybe ask about Total War and start from there. But we would also need your system specifications including the direct x your running, and confirmation of actually installing the direct X versions listed under each game. (note: Direct X **is designed to be universal**; You should not need 9 if you have 10. I have had to use Direct X for development, and believe me, there are exceptions to this rule)

Comment: Vista Home Premium (SP2)
Intel Core2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz
8Gb Ram
NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT
DirectX 11

Comment: @user130843 Launch the game, then launch Event Viewer. Under *Windows Logs* -> *Application*, see if there is any issues reported there.

Comment: If you have an antivirus program, did you try disabling it before running the games?

Comment: No issues when I attempt to launch @Robotnik.

Comment: Yeah, tried disabling AV progs @Alexander Revo

Comment: @user130843 - ok, try opening Task Manager, and on the Processes tab - is the game process still running?

Comment: @Robotnik Nope. Process starts but immediately ends

Comment: @user130843 really? and there's nothing at all in Event Viewer? Not in any of the other tabs either? no events (including Info/Warning) with the same timestamp?

Comment: @Robotnik No, plenty of events in the event viewer but none with timestamps correlating to me attempting to launch the games it seems.

Answer (score -6):

The solution to your question is quite simple. Upgrade to Windows 7, and get rid of Windows Vista.

Comment: Why does this fix it?  Why is Vista the problem?

Comment: @Frank vista is always the problem

Comment: I have vista and it works well for me